# What is the best Adobe program to create a cover for a guideline?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, adobe-indesign

i am working on a visual merchandising guideline and trying to create an awesome cover for it! nice layout not really busy one!
but i am really confused which program is the best to use in this case, I have created this cover, but i am not really crazy about it! is there any tips guys you[image] can give me?  i would really appreciate it!

Comment: Are your questions related, i.e., do you believe just using another program will make you go crazy about it?

Comment: It doesn't matter what application you use, especially when we are talking about: Indesign, Illustrator and Photoshop. Using one over the other does not affect the quality of your design. Only the workflow, efficiency and file size. Perhaps other small things too.

Answer (score 2):

I would layout a cover like this in InDesign. Especially if the document has many other pages following. The photos I would edit in Photoshop and if there was any more complex vector graphics I would use Illustrator to do this.

You could probably do the whole thing except the photo editing with any of those tools though. The tool for lay outing pages is Indesign though.

Answer (score 1):

Best is not defined, one of my pet peeves. Best in this case depends on what you know how to use.

You will naturally get the answer that you should use InDesign because you mention the word 'cover'. This leads people to think about print publication and the correct answer for designing publications is InDesign. But this answer also casually glosses over the fact that InDesign relies on Illustrator and Photoshop for asset creation.

So then your still at odds which to use. If i would be forced to pick only one application i would pick Illustrator. That is a bit synthetic tough not many days go by that i dont use both illustrator and photoshop both at the same time for the same artwork. Im not even a graphic designer. The 3 main software illustrator, photoshop and indesign comlmplemen each other.

Answer (score 0):

If your works related to printing medias, I suggest you to use [InDesign](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/indesign.html).

If you have knowledge to work in Photoshop, It will be easy to learn to work with InDesign.

Having clear understanding about Pixels, Vectors and resolutions will give better quality to work

Comment: any samples you can suggest?

Comment: i need to do some layout and nice effects, but i am not really sure how!

Comment: You can draw rectangles/textboxes with InDesign. Also you can change the fonts colors will give you the exact result.

Comment: It is the professional tool to create the designs in Publications

Comment: You can produce PDF files too for Monitor publish